# React make parent Route inaccessible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a React app with React Router v6, my routes are as follows

```
<Route path="/checkout" element={<CheckoutLayout />} >
  <Route path="shipment" element={<ShipmentPage />} />
  <Route path="payment" element={<PaymentPage />} />
</Route>
```

With these routes I can access 3 routes

```
/checkout
/checkout/shipment
/checkout/payment
```

I want the first route to be inaccessible, because it's a layout with an **Outlet**, how can I achieve this?

```
<>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <Outlet />
  <h1>Footer</h1>
</>
```

Edit:
In **CheckoutLayout** I wrote

```
export const CheckoutLayout = () => {

  if (window.location.href === `url/checkout`) {
    return <Navigate to="/checkout/payment" />
  }

  return <div></div>
}
```